# Run user-submitted code in Go

Tags: go, eval, user-input

I am working on an application which allows users to compare the execution of different string comparison algorithms.  In addition to several algorithms (including [Boyer-Moore](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), [KMP](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), and other "traditional" ones) that are included, I want to allow users to put in their own algorithms (these could be their own algorithms or modifications to the existing ones) to compare them.

Is there some way in Go to take code from the user (for example, from an HTML textarea) and execute it?

More specifically, I want the following characteristics:

- I provide a method signature and they fill in whatever they want in the method.
- A crash or a syntax error in their code should not cause my whole program to crash.  It should instead allow me to catch the error and display an error message.

(In this case, I am not worried about security against malicious code because users will only be executing my program on their own machines, so security is their own responsibility.)

If it is not possible to do this natively with Go, I am open to embedding one of the following languages to use for the comparison functions (in order of preference): JavaScript, Python, Ruby, C.  Is there any way to do any of those?

Comment: Slightly differing from Volker's take, it's possible, just very hard. play.golang.org uses Google Native Client and a pared-down standard library and GOMAXPROCS=1 (otherwise race conditions can break type safety). It also changes the stdlib (and maybe runtime?) to stub out time/net/filesystem functions, adds caching, and adds runtime and memory limits. Seems like maybe NaCl + low-privileged container process and VM + time and memory limit + caching + validating that input is a single Go function (within a package without dangerous imports) could help protect you, but it's hard.

Comment: @twotwotwo At the heart of it, they are only compiling and running your code, then returning the output. All the other stuff is security and resource limiting. Since users will be running my project on their own machines, I don't really care about the security and memory limit parts here.

Comment: Oh, noted, skimmed over that in your question--then you'd need to distribute Go with your project and call Go as an external process to build it. There are lots of small ([TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/)?) choices. Client-side JS is no joke nowadays either, might be easiest since you're talking about an HTML textarea already; you could look around to see what's lowest-overhead/"fairest" to different algos (e.g., JS string vs. JS number array vs. `Uint8Array`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clear No.

But you can do fancy stuff: Why not recompile the program including the user provided code? 
Split the stuff into two: One driver which collects user code, recompiles the actual code, executes the actual code and reports the outcome.

Including other interpreters for other languages can be done, e.g. Otto is a Javascript interpreter. (C will be hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing something similar to the [gopherjs playground](http://gopherjs.org/playground/)?  According to [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8454604), the compilation is being done client-side.